# Mapping States to zipcodes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a cleansed pandas dataframe that just contains a single column of zip codes, and I'm trying to use pyzipcode to return the corresponding state in a new column by executing:

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
import pandas as pd
import os
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()

df = pd.read_excel(r'G:\Downloads\testzip.xlsx')
df[pd.to_numeric(df['Zip'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
df = df.dropna

df['state'] = df['Zip'].map(lambda x: zcdb[x].state)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

'method' object is not subscriptable

No idea why. Anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of dataset?

Comment: Please show the full error message in a code block.

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback. Absent this, I bet it's caused by `df['state']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = df.dropna` replaces your dataframe by its `dropna` method. This causes `df['Zip']` to raise the exception you see. Replace it with `df = df.dropna()`, which calls the method instead - I am fairly sure that's what you want.

Comment: You got it, thanks! Such a silly mistake on my part